# What happens when an esper reachs level 6?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun, a-certain-scientific-accelerator

In the Toaru series several characters are trying to reach level 6, like Accelerator and Hirumi. But what happens when an esper reachs this level? Is this ever told in the series, mangas, spinoffs or light novels?